# Creating links from an ID in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm retrieving data from different tables in my application that contain only the music_id of an Artist.

What I want to do is create a user friendly link which also includes the artists name. This requires a query of the original artist table but the problem I'm having is knowing where abouts inside of codeigniter I should be doing this? I'm retrieving the latest news inside of the model and passing an array of results from the controller to the view that look like this:

```
id | music_id | source 
 1     22        url
 2     98        url
```

and displaying them via a foreach loop. but what I want is to create a link that contains the music_ids name so users know what page they are going to. eg `<a href="music/artist/22">Pink Floyd</a>`

Should I be doing this in the model before sending data to the view? or by using a class/function inside of the view to create a link from the ID?

Comment: Views should concentrate on displaying the data, not business logic.

Comment: How could I go about passing through a pre-made link with the name before hand then? run another foreach loop on the original result appending a link for each row?

Answer (score 1):

Just generate your link in the view. Something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('music/artist/'.$artist->id); ?>"><?php echo $artist->name; ?></a>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo anchor('music/artist/'.$artist->id, $artist->name); ?>
```

Both `site_url()` and `anchor()` require you to load the URL Helper somewhere (autoloading it is easiest).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't have access to the Artists name from the original result set though.. I only have the artists ID number, So another query is necessary first?

Comment: If you need that name, then yes you should incorporate it into your query somewhere. A simple `JOIN` would retrieve the matching artist's info with your query.

Comment: Thanks again, only trouble with that is I'm making queries and outputting data all over the site relating to artists in activity feeds, gigs, related artists, followers, likes etc. some of the database queries are very long already and I want it to be from a centralized function incase of a URL change. 
Before converting to codeigniter I had a special class for creating links from id's that I used to call inside of loops but not sure as to how I should do this kind of thing in codeigniter.

Comment: I'd avoid creating links in anything except your views, but it could be useful. I don't know enough about your DB or application to say what your best case would be.